# Using onclick to filter the tab on menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im working on a project which there is multiple menu selection on tab which i need to onclick on each tab menu will display different type of menuFood. As my jquery not working on the function with onclick and the tab will add class "on" and the display of the table will be different. Kindly advice

html：

```
<div class="tab" data-type="wx" data-desc="整合"> 
    <span data-type="wx" class="on">整合</span>
    <span data-type="sx">第一球</span>
    <span data-type="qsm">第二球</span>
    <span data-type="zsm">第三球</span>
    <span data-type="hsm">第四球</span>
    <span data-type="em">第五球</span> 
</div>
```

jquery：

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){  
         $('.tab span').each(function(){  
            if($($(this))[0].href==String(window.location))  
                $(this).parent().addClass('on');  
         });  
     })  
</script>
```

Comment: You are using `href` here, but there is no `a` tag is present in your html ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz im sorry i dint use href to onclick as the function onclick

Comment: why do you double wrap 'this' in the if statement?

Comment: you aren't changing the location on click. how will it ever match?

Comment: @FelixHäberle i thought it will be easier to route into other web to change the particular of the web to change the div element

Comment: @Rhea is that possible without href to onclick the span and add class ?

Comment: @MorganNg yes. u can add a hash to the url . what output do u expect.

Comment: @MorganNg check out the answer that changes the location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to handle the clicked element:

```js
var $spans = $('.tab span');
$spans.on('click', function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  $spans.removeClass('on');
  $el.addClass('on');
  
  // Your logic to use type
  console.log('Clicked:', $el.data('type'));
});
```

```css
.on {color: red;}
.tab span {cursor: pointer; margin: 10px;}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab" data-type="wx" data-desc="整合"> 
  <span data-type="wx" class="on">整合</span>
  <span data-type="sx">第一球</span>
  <span data-type="qsm">第二球</span>
  <span data-type="zsm">第三球</span>
  <span data-type="hsm">第四球</span>
  <span data-type="em">第五球</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: THanks its really help

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 

       // to preselect the span from the hash whenever u refresh the page.
       $('span[data-type="'+location.hash.substr(1)+'"]').addClass('on') 
        $('.tab span').click(function(){
         $(this).siblings().removeClass('on');
           $(this).addClass('on')
           location.hash = $(this).data('type')
        })
    })
```